# How to intertwine 2 JSON files into one associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to take 2 similar JSON files being pulled into an HTML doc via jQuery and intertwine them so that the first items of both become items 1 and 2 of a new associative array, the second items become 3 and 4, and so on.

**Example:**

```
var JSON1 = {'Item 1':123, 'Item 2':234, 'Item 3': 345}
var JSON2 = {'Item 1':555, 'Item 2':666, 'Item 3': 777}
var newArray = {'Item 1':123, 'Item 1':555, 'Item 2':234, 'Item 2':666, 'Item 3': 345, 'Item 3': 777}
```

The one caveat is the actual JSON files are 2-level arrays. However, I just need to intertwine the first level.

I'm finding a lot of great solutions for simply merging arrays, but not in this fashion. Any ideas?

Comment: For the record, those are Javascript objects, not JSON. I also don't understand what you mean by 2-level arrays. An example would help.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. An object in JavaScript cannot have duplicate keys.

What you can do is to make value of each key an array like this:

```
{'Item 1':[123, 555], 'Item 2': [234, 666], 'Item 3': [345, 777]}
```

Comment: Let's say that the corresponding keys weren't exactly the same (no key conflicts) and that you just wanted to associate the items in their respective order. I can adjust the JSON files so there's a slight differentiation between the corresponding keys.

Comment: To clarify the last comment, the keys could be "Item 1" and "Item 1b", "Item 2" and "Item 2b", etc.

Comment: @Mark Kanning, do the objects have the exact same number of keys?

Comment: Yes, they'll have the same number of keys by design. The data sets being merged are analogous to each other, just with different values. In essence, one data set is a benchmark of optimum values, the other is the actual values. Getting over the redundant keys isn't a problem. It's the merging that's the problem.